# Failed to connect mongodb from shell / robomongo. But connected via nodejs code

Tags: node.js, mongodb, shell

I have tried to connect the mongodb from shell using the following command.

```
mongo xxxxx.mongolab.com:47612/dbname -u user -p password
```

But I am getting the error : **Error: 18 Authentication failed**.

Same authorization failure when I try to connect from Robomongo.

But when I tried to connect mongodb from my NodeJS code, its working perfect.

NodeJS Code:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://user:password@xxxxx.mongolab.com:47612/dbname',
function (err){
 if (err) throw err;
 console.log("db connected")
});
```

Also I tried to change the bind IP in *mongod.conf* from 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0

Issue still exists.